# Swift - touch drag exit to create shape

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift and I would like to have a button in my app that, if I click on it and drag my finger out of its boundaries, will create a new shape. That shape would have been created with a nice transition like shown below.

Link where you can see the full transition: https://iosexample.com/tools-for-swiftui-that-helps-perform-path-and-shape-animations/

After two hours looking for a tutorial that could lead me to that result, I still have no clue on how that can be done. So, if someone could explain me how he would do it or the strategy to have to solve that kind of challenge, that would be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: I smell some Bézier curve shenanigans...